# how the constraint in equation 11b converted to equation 16 using sequential convex approximation method

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

[the constraint that I want to transfer to convex shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gZ8b.png)

[the inequality that used to transfer it with the sequential convex approximation method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAYiM.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).